# How to localize the origin of a HDF5 error message?

Tags: c++, hdf5

Somewhere in my application a HDF error occurs, but all i get are number of messages on stderr:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 1561 in H5Aexists(): not a location
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 246 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5Adeprec.c line 196 in H5Aopen_name(): not a location
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 246 in H5G_loc(): invalid object ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 704 in H5Aget_space(): not an attribute
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5S.c line 921 in H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims(): not a dataspace
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5S.c line 1013 in H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(): not a dataspace
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5S.c line 489 in H5Sclose(): not a dataspace
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5A.c line 1523 in H5Aclose(): not an attribute
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
```

Is there a way to find out where in my code the error occurred, and/or what the arguments to the problematic calls (e.e. `H5Aexists()`, or `H5Aopen_name()` are?
(I mean other than enclosing every HDF5 call with debug messages)

Comment: You can acquire hdf5 sources and place breakpoints in mentioned files, then look at call stack to find exact methods in your code that result in these errors

Comment: Do you expect a callee to show info about its caller? You should check the status every time you call hdf5 api.

Comment: @nimrod: with finding the location i didn't mean that HDF% should give me info about the caller. Rather, i meant something like a setting which would cause HDF5 to abort the program, which in turn would enable me to track the location with a debugger.

Comment: I am afraid not, at least idk. I go to check the code of libhdf5, the apis report the error and return an error code rather than abort or throw an exception, so whether you want to  use it correctly or debug, you'd better check the error code and cope with the errors.  A tricky way to debug may be to set breakpoints on `H5E_printf_stack` since all error reporting will call this function.